# How can I continue page number after pdf merging using flyingsaucer library in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

**Use case** : I need to merge pdf and the page number is continue after previous pdf merge.

**Problem** : On each pdf my page number reset to 1.

**Each PDF Generate Code**

```
byte[] generatePDFBytes = htmlpdfUtil.create().body(reportStringSloatWise.toString())
                        .printSettingTemplateMaster(
                                getTemplateMastrerFinal(printSettingTemplateMaster, entryTime, lastEntry))
                        .pageOrientation(PageOrientation.LongSize1).topSpacingForOtherheader(30).autoPrint(false)
                        .buildHtmlAndPDF().generatePDFBytes();
```

**Page Number Generate Code**

```
pagenumberDiv = pagenumberDiv.replace(HTMLPageFormat.Page_Number.getDisplayCode(), "<span id='pagenumber'></span>");
```

**Page Number Genrate Using Counter(CSS)**

```
#pagenumber:before {
    content: counter(page);
}
```

**PDF Merging Code(We convert multiple byte array into one)**

```
 public static void mergePortraitAndLandscapePdfFiles(List<byte[]> inputPdfList, OutputStream outputStream) {
    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        PdfReader reader;
        int n;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputPdfList.size(); i++) {
            reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfList.get(i));
            n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
            }
            copy.freeReader(reader);
            reader.close();
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    logger.info("Pdf files merged successfully.");
}
```

**Dependency that we use**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```